# jQuery Inline onClick VS $(selector).click Precedence

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to make a `$(selector).click(function)` run before, or preceed, an inline `onClick="function"`?

Also, if possible, I would like to stop the inline function from running entirely (by using `preventDefault()` inside the `$(selector).click()`).

Here's a fiddle to illustrate the precedence: http://jsfiddle.net/yUZWR/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant the anchor ID to be called `link` and not `#link`, this is how to reverse the function execution order...

```
var v = $('#link').attr('onclick');

$('#link').removeAttr('onclick').click(function(){
    alert('captured');
    return false;
}).click(function() { eval(v); })
```

I'm certain there's a better way of doing this i.e., not using `eval`. To prevent the inline function running altogether, just omit the second call to `click`.